# Google visualization events after drag listener

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, listener, chap-links-library

I am using the Chap Links Timeline plugin to create an application.
I have draggable events on the timeline, and I am trying to add a listener that will trigger when an event has been dragged, but I cannot find how to add this.

I have sever other listeners for select, add etc that do work:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(timeline, 'select', onselect);
google.visualization.events.addListener(timeline, 'change', onchange);
google.visualization.events.addListener(timeline, 'add', onadd);
google.visualization.events.addListener(timeline, 'edit', onedit);
google.visualization.events.addListener(timeline, 'delete', ondelete);
```

but none of these, even change, are not triggered when an event is dragged.

I was hoping that someone has tried and managed to add this kind of listener.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

To listen to a change on an event in the timeline I had to add the changed (with a d) listener:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(timeline, 'changed', onEventChange);
```